# JButton not in the right spot with 2 classes

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Don't know how to over simplify this but when I tried to put the buttons in a different location it wouldn't move. I suppose its because of the BorderLayout, I looked and couldn't find much that applied to this. Thanks for the help! Im new to coding and this is a new thing that I'm learning.

```
public class MazeMouse extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    JButton d,k;
    int button = 0;
    
    
    MazeMouse(){
        setBackground(Color.black);
        
        
        k = new JButton("Press To Finish");
        d = new JButton("Press To Begin");
        add(d);
    add(k);
        
k.addActionListener(this);  
          d.addActionListener(this);
    }
    
    
    @Override
    
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    
       
           if(button == 1) {
                 g2.setColor(Color.red);
                g2.fillRect(300,0,200,50);
               g2.fillRect(375, 50, 50, 200);
               g2.fillRect(375,525,50,200);
               g2.fillRect(300, 725, 200, 50);
           }
            
        
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 if(e.getSource()==d)
 {      
     button++;
     d.setEnabled(false);
     repaint();
 }
 
 
 if(e.getSource()==k) {
    setBackground(Color.green);
 }
        
    }

    
    
}
```

And class MM

```
public class MM implements MouseMotionListener,ActionListener {
    JFrame f;    
    MazeMouse p; 
    
    int button = 0;
    public MM(){    
        
        f = new JFrame(); 
        Container c = f.getContentPane();    
                c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());   
              
    
                
                p = new MazeMouse();   
        c.add(p); 
        
        
        f.setSize(800,800);    
        f.setVisible(true);    
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
    
    
    
    }
    public static void main(String args[ ]){    
        MM t = new MM();     
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    } 
}
```

Comment: *I suppose its because of the BorderLayout* No. You set a `BorderLayout` on the main frame (redundant actually as that's already the default layout) but your buttons aren't on it anyway - they're on the panel in a `FlowLayout` (the default). Where and how do you want them?

Comment: I’d like them to go too middle and bottom middle of the screen where the red rectangles are

Comment: This is not normally something to recommend but since you're drawing with absolute coordinates, you could actually place your buttons with absolute coordinates after setting a null layout. I would ensure that resizing cannot happen

Comment: Whenever I set the layout as null I get an error. And if I set bounds to a button it doesn’t work. What do I exactly do?

Comment: Please post that code. Your start button bounds should be something like `Rectangle startBounds = new Rectangle(400-180/2, 0, 180, 40);`

Comment: I’ll be able to post it once I get into class. Thanks!

Comment: This is what I Have now. The button still doesn't move?`MazeMouse(){
  Rectangle startBounds = new Rectangle(400-180/2, 0, 180, 40);
  setBackground(Color.black);
  
  
  k = new JButton("Press To Finish");
  d = new JButton("Press To Begin");
  add(d);
 add(k);
        d.setBounds(startBounds);
        
k.addActionListener(this); 
          d.addActionListener(this);
 }`

Comment: You need to `setLayout(null)`

Comment: I did do that, What happened was it never opened. (the frame)

Comment: Bottom button not quite right but general ideas is http://technojeeves.com/tech/MazeMouse.java

Comment: 1) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the intended layout of the GUI. 2) Use a logical and consent form of code indentation. IDEs have a shortcut to format code. 3) Since the problem is layouts, remove all the listener code. Focus on what needs fixing. 4) Code looks horrid in comments (as you can see above). Instead [edit] the question.